# Update PDF with acrobat form

Tags: java, pdfbox, acrobat

We are using AcroForm to update the fillable PDF. We are facing issue when trying to fill a larger text/data in the available field, Data is getting hidden due to less space (form filed size).

I currently have a pre-made PDF, which I have gone and used Adobe Acrobat PRO to create some entry fields within the PDF.Once I have completed the entire form, I would like to use Java to run through the PDF fill in the form with the associated information from some data (JSON/database), and re-save the PDF.

We are using PDFbox to fill the data, but its not working as expected. Could you please suggest some better approach where I can use acroform to fill the data using java and rows can be shifted based on data available i.e. form field size can be adjusted automatically as per data size.

Please find attached image where we are filling data as "Arvind Kumar Mishra 1234567899999 xsd test" on of the acrobat form field but only "Arvind Kumar Mishra 1234567899999" is getting displayed. Remaining data "  xsd test " is not visible.

Could you please help on same. If we can do the same with open source tool, it would be great, but any suggestion would appreciable.

[image]

Comment: Please share the PDF and include the code that you tried. Also consider my text from the pdfbox user mailing list.

Comment: This comes close to your problem, i.e. it gets the font and gets the width: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644015/detecting-text-field-overflow The only thing missing is enlarging the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the solution provided over there. Getting the font and getting the width is fine. My requirement is to enlarge the rectangle so that entered data can fit properly in the document. If required the data  after rectangle can be shifted in next line.

Comment: As I wrote in the user mailing list, call setRectangle () on the widgets.